# Using bash and jq and reading in a json file with \n in the contents

Tags: json, bash, jq

Need some help with jq and reading in a json file that must have \n values because I need to import it into something else later. How can I have jq interpret it as a literal \n instead of the line breaks below....?  Notice my json has a \n and I want it like that. I don't want it to treat it as a carriage return like it's doing in the output

file.json (note the \n in the description)

```
{
"person": [
    {
        "name": "Alex",
        "age": "10",
        "description": "A really\nnice kid"
    },
    {
        "name": "James",
        "age": "17",
        "description": "One mature\nBoy who\ndoes his homework"
    }
]
```

}

Script:

```
jq -r -M '.person[] | .name + " " + .description' file.json  \
| while IFS=$' ' read -r  nameX  descriptionX; do
echo "${nameX} ${descriptionX}"
echo "----------------------------------------done---------------------"
done
```

Wrong Output right now it's doing this:

```
Alex A really
----------------------------------------done---------------------
nice kid
----------------------------------------done---------------------
James One mature
----------------------------------------done---------------------
Boy who
----------------------------------------done---------------------
does his homework
----------------------------------------done---------------------
```

It should look like this, but it looks like the one above. How can I make it look like this.

```
Alex A really\nnice kid
----------------------------------------done---------------------
James One mature\nBoy who\ndoes his homework
----------------------------------------done---------------------
```

Comment: Your "it should look like this" section doesn't seem to match the description -- it appears to have turned the newlines into spaces, not either `\n` or actual newlines.

Comment: @JimmyChen - Please review what you have written carefully, and then clarify the requirements, perhaps giving a second example if the requirements are complex. Can the requirements be stated functionally? Is the use of a shell `while` loop one of the requirements?

Comment: @peak  thanks. I made some modifications to my post.  Basically, it's outputting what I put above when it should look like what I put in the "It should look like this? any help" section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The requirements are unclear, so here are three approaches that might be (or might be the basis for) solutions:

#### 1. jq+sed

```
jq  -M '.person[] | .name + " " + .description' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
```

#### 2. jq+read+sed

```
jq  -M '.person[] | .name + " " + .description'  |
  while IFS=$' ' read -r line ; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//'
    echo "----------------------------------------done---------------------"
  done
```

#### 3. jq + (read+sed)^2

```
jq -M '.person[] | .name, .description'  |
  threewhile IFS=$' ' read -r name ; do
    name=$(sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<< $name)
    read -r description
    description=$(sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<< $description)
    echo "$name $description" 
    echo "----------------------------------------done---------------------"
  done
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response. Actually, you know what the issue was... I had -r

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this directly in `jq`, by replacing actual newlines (which are represented by `\n` in JSON strings) with literal `\` and `n` characters:

```
$ jq -r -M '.person[] | .name + " " + (.description | gsub("\n"; "\\n"))' file.json
Alex A really\nnice kid
James One mature\nBoy who\ndoes his homework
```

And feeding it into your `while read` loop:

```
$ jq -r -M '.person[] | .name + " " + (.description | gsub("\n"; "\\n"))' file.json |
> while IFS=$' ' read -r  nameX  descriptionX; do
> echo "${nameX} ${descriptionX}"
> echo "----------------------------------------done---------------------"
> done
Alex A really\nnice kid
----------------------------------------done---------------------
James One mature\nBoy who\ndoes his homework
----------------------------------------done---------------------
```